# Project ID Required to Access Firestore Error

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-admin

I wish to use the firebase admin-sdk but for some reason, I am getting a "project id is required to access Firestore error".

I have downloaded an admin-sdk json file from the firebase console and I have placed it in the same directory as the file that calls it.

`opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("../<FILENAME>.json")`

The credentials file has the project id but for some reason the `opt` variable is unable to extract data from the credentials file, and as a result when I try to get the firestore client this error is occuring.

Thanks!

Comment: Which directory are you locating credential file? `../<FILENAME>.json` looks you are locating the file in the parent directory of exec file. Is it so?

Comment: So I have the src folder and within that I have another folder called firebase_client where there is a go file calling the credential file which is also in firebase_client. The exec file is located within the src folder.

Comment: Try specify the credential file with full path.

Comment: Tried it again from the repository root path and still nothing

Comment: No, not from the repository root, but absolute path from the machine root.

Comment: Not working, I tried to use the os pkg to read the json file from the machine root and it's able to successfully read it yet when I put the same address into the CredentialsFile method I get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233533/discussion-between-sree-grandhe-and-n-f).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved, I was using the wrong absolute path.

Comment: I think the SDK should print more precise error message.

Comment: Yeah a good error message from the SDK would be great!